# Segmentation failed (core dumped), C

Tags: c, arrays, string, getchar

I have the following programme:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 100
//a)
bool isPalyndrom(char c[], int cnt) {
    int i;
    char pal[MAX];
    int j = 0;
    for (i = cnt - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        pal[j] = c[i];
        j++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        if (c[i] != pal[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    char c, s[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    do {
        c = getchar();
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
        cnt++;
        printf("\n%s\n", s);
    } while (c != '\n');
    printf("%d", cnt);
    bool istrue = isPalyndrom(s, cnt);
    if (istrue) {
        printf("\n%s Pal.\n", s);
    } else {
        printf("\n%s not Pal.\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it, is shown: segmentation fault, the problem is in the do-while loop, the programme stops, after my char c are written in the array and before the do-while loop is left. Could somebody take a look in the do-while loop?

Comment: The problem is in the `isPalindrome()` function. Carefully check the indices in the loops under that function.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, the s char array is not initialized.  So, its likely not null terminated, and the printf in the do-while loop will be an issue.  Do a memset on s to zero, and it should be better.

Comment: Is it really segmentation "failed"?

Comment: Yes, but it`s solved , i wrote this: c=getchar();
while(c!='\n'){
s[i]=c;
i++;
cnt++;
c=getchar();
} plus corrected that comical i++, that I wrote by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in this loop

```
int j=0;
for(i=cnt-1; i>=0; i++){
                   ^^^^
pal[j]=c[i];
j++;
}
```

I think you mean `i--`

Also you did not assign the terminatinbg zero to array `s`  So using for example
this statement

```
printf("\n%s\n",s);
```

in this do-while loop

```
do{
c=getchar();
s[i]=c;
i++;
cnt++;
printf("\n%s\n",s);
}while(c!='\n');
```

is wrong.

Besides you included the new line character in the array s.

Take into account that the function can be written simpler without using an auxiliary array. For example

```
bool isPalyndrom( const char s[], size_t n ) 
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n-i-1] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}
```

Comment: also, in the `printf` function, I think he means the symbol `\n`, not `n`. (actually that's why the do-while loop not worked)

Comment: @FalconUA Where is there n you are speaking about?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes it's clear. In any case the solution could be:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define MAX 100

bool isPalyndrom(char c[]) {
    int strLen = strlen(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen / 2; i++){
        if (c[i] != c[strLen - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    char c, s[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        s[i++] = c;
    } 
    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("%d", strlen(s));
    bool istrue = isPalyndrom(s);
    if (istrue){
        printf("\n%s Pal.\n", s);
    } else {
        printf("\n%s not Pal.\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```